# People picker not working in Chrome under taxonomy central admin

Tags: people-picker, bug

Here is a google chrome bug I logged with MS connect.

https://connect.microsoft.com/site428/feedback/details/632134/people-picker-in-google-chrome-not-working-sometimes#details

Make sure you expand the reproduction steps, but here they are again:

- Using Google Chrome: Open up central administration
- Navigate to : Central Administration > Site Settings > Term Store Management Tool
- Try and select a Term Store Administrators . For example, manually type in "administrator".
- Wait for cursor to refresh
- Notice the box clears of any input and anything you typed is lost.

If you can reproduce this issue, please support this bug to get it fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome is not a supported browser. This is not a bug.

Comment: Additionally, only Firefox is a non-MS level 1 browser on window, Safari is Level 2 I believe. Chrome works sometimes but it's not currently supported. I reckon Google throw out far too many minor releases for MS UI guys to keep testing and updating.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification. Wonder what is so special about the people picker control that it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: I seem to recall it's an ActiveX component.  It doesn't work properly in 2007/Firefox.