# People editor data visible in IE but not in Chrome, SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, browser-compatibility

People editor data is visible in IE but not in Chrome. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

It's just not supported in Chrome.

> About planning browser support SharePoint Server 2010 supports several
>   commonly used Web browsers. However, certain Web browsers might cause
>   some SharePoint Server 2010 functionality to be downgraded, limited,
>   or available only through alternative steps. In some cases,
>   functionality might be unavailable for noncritical administrative
>   tasks.

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Similar post [People picker not working in Chrome under taxonomy central admin](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7905/people-picker-not-working-in-chrome-under-taxonomy-central-admin)

Comment: Hi , Thanx for reply . Why it is not supported in chome ?

Comment: Here is the browser support document from Microsoft for 2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx. I'm not able to find anything regarding People editor and Chrome being unsupported. Can you enlighten me? :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren what I said was based on personal experience and as article states, browsers are supported but some functionality might not be available :)

Comment: Sure, but isn't most of that stuff nowadays Active X-based? Is the people editor using some Active-X goodies?

Comment: @RobertLindgren People Editor control might have Ajax control in it as it's has AutoPost back property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditor.autopostback(v=office.14).aspx